# Enable/Disable swiper dynamically (touch/mouse)

Tags: angularjs, swiper.js

I have a page with a question and 4 answers, the swiper works great, I can go  to the next question and back. What I want is to disable the swipe to the next question until an answer has been pressed. I successfully hide the 'next' arrow with a $scope variable and ng-show but the swipe with touch/mouse still works even after calling the initSwiper function with the new disabled options everytime I press an answer. Is this possible? This is the current initSwiper function that works really good.

```
$scope.initSwiper = function() {
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            // Navigation arrows
            nextButton : '.swiper-button-next',
            slideToClickedSlide : true,
            onSlideChangeStart : function(swiper) {
                $scope.index = swiper.activeIndex;
                setExplanation($scope.index);
                $scope.$apply();
                $scope.test = $scope.tests[$scope.index];
                swiper.lockSwipeToPrev();
            }
        }); 
    }
```

My other init function that I call after an answer has been pressed it is just like this, I only add this `swiper.lockSwipeToNext()` to `onSlideChangeStart: function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `noSwipingClass` option when you init the Swiper and use your `$scope` to conditionally apply a css class such as `no-answer-yet` to the Swiper slides. So something like:

```
$scope.initSwiper = function() {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      ...,
      noSwipingClass: "no-answer-yet",
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, it works perfectly now! Your idea is so easy and straightforward!